# jQuery not selector mixed with greater than filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to write a selector like this:

```
$('.hide:not(.login-form, .custom-school-container, .school_select:gt(1))').removeClass('hide')
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .hide:not(.login-form, .custom-school-container, .school_select
```

I am obviously mixing up my syntax, but I thought you could include the `:gt(index)` in with a `:not` selector.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? the selector should work fine.

Comment: I figured it out! Putting my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This was the way I wound up getting it to work

```
$('.hide:not(.login-form, .custom-school-container)').filter('.school_select:gt(1)').removeClass('hide')
```